# Creating folders and subfolders coming from a text file

Tags: bash

I have a scenario which will create a new directories coming from a text file.

newDirectory.txt

```
/test/test1
/test/test1/test2
```

I used this code but I tend to get double test1 subfolder

```
while IFS="" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ]
    do 
      mkdir -p "$p" &&
      chmod -R 770 "$p"
    done < newDirectory.txt
```

Assuming that test main folder is already created.
I got 2 test1 folder.
One has additional "^M" (/test/test1^M) but with no subfolder
and one has the expected folder with subfolder inside (/test/test1/test2)

The text file should also be reference when deleting the created folder

```
while IFS="" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ]
    do 
      rm -rf $p
    done < newDirectory.txt
```

But only the /test/test1/test2 was deleted and /test/test1 still exist.
Thank you

Comment: Not sure if it's your issue, but the "^M" char is usually a Windows line ending that made it into the file. You can run the file through `dos2unix` which will fix it, or try looking for it with vim/some editor. That should cause the script to create and delete the correct folders

Comment: Could you please confirm that your `newDirectory.txt` file is a DOS text file that was edited or created on a Windows operating system?

Answer (score 4):

You were already told that your text file probably contains DOS line endings (CR+LF), so in the UNIX world it looks like

```
/test/test1^M
/test/test1/test2^M
```

with the carriage return `^M` invisible depending on the editor you use.

So what happens? For the first line, the folder with trailing carriage return `^M` is created, while the second one creates `test1` without `^M` due to the `-p` option.

Then on removing, the `test1^M` folder is removed as well the the subfolder `test1/test2^M`, but nobody requests to remove the auto-created folder `test1`.

Soltution: Remove the wrong line endings. If you don't have `dos2unix` at hand, use

```
sed -i.bak 's/^M$//' newDirectory.txt
```

(insert the `^M` by typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>).

Btw, when using `bash`, don't forget to quote the `"$p"` in the `rm` line.